# Getting org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException for Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error and I have checked the documentation and even the basic program [on the documentation page](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) is giving this error.

- **chromedriver : 2.44**
- **chrome version : 74**

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.
>           Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27
>   09:10:26'
>           System info: host: 'HIDINGACTUALHOST', ip: '10.10.10.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>           Driver info: driver.version: Driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are using [chrome driver 2.44](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) which is only supported `chrome v69-v71`.

You need to [download chrome driver 74](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=74.0.3729.6/) for `chrome v74`

**Note** : You can see all the details related chrome driver [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)